# GCDAsyncSocket Client Public Key

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ssl, gcdasyncsocket

I made a simple TLS Server with GCDAsyncSocket and want to get the clients public key. I tried using this:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    SSLContextRef ref = [sock sslContext];
    SecTrustRef trust;
    SSLCopyPeerTrust(ref, &trust);

    SecKeyRef key = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);
    NSLog(@"%@",key);
}
```

but i get a exc_bad_access in the SecTrustCopyPublicKey method. How can i get the public key  as a NSString/NSData?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure there's an SSL connection? Does your `didSecure` delegate method invoked?
2. Check your `trust` reference is not `NULL` after the `SSLCopyPeerTrust` function performed.
3. There's a discussion about the `SecTrustCopyPublicKey` on the [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices) provided by the Apple.

> You must call the [SecTrustEvaluate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecTrustEvaluate) function before calling this
>   function. When you call this function, it attempts to return the
>   public key of the leaf certificate, even if the trust evaluation was
>   unsuccessful. Even if the trust evaluation was successful, this
>   function might still return NULL—for example, if the leaf
>   certificate’s key can’t be extracted for some reason.